# Applying labels from a data frame with values and labels

Tags: r

How can I label a variable with the label stored in a data frame in R.

I have a data frame like this:

| Name | Sex |
| --- | --- |
| Ind 1 | 1 |
| Ind 2 | 2 |
| Ind 3 | 1 |
| Ind 4 | 2 |
| Ind 5 | 2 |
| Ind 6 | 1 |
| Ind 7 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

And a data frame with the labels for `Sex`

| Code | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Male |
| 2 | Female |

How can I label the `Sex` variable in the first data frame with the labels stored in the second data frame?

Comment: Check the 'labelled' Package, specifically the 'set_val_labels' function. Alternatively, you can turn your variable into a factor variable.

Comment: `inner_join(df, labels, by = c(Sex = "Code")) %>% select(Name, Sex = Label)`

Comment: Do you just want to merge the data? Or replace it? Base R doesn't really do "labels" for values. Are you coming from a different language or something? Or what exactly is the requirement? What do you need to do with the data after you've made the transformation?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

Note: For future use and finding friends here, please always provide a reproducible example.

**example data**

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Ind1","Ind2","Ind3","Ind4","Ind5"), Sex = c(1,2,1,2,2))
df2<- data.frame(Code = c(1,2), Label = c("Male","Female"))
```

**label by position**
You can use the index of a vector element to "overwrite" it with another vector of "labels".

The following stores the result in a new column. Obviously, you can overwrite your Sex column with the result.

```
df$Sex2 <- df2$Label[df$Sex]
```

**joining**
The other more general way to do this is to join your data frames.

```
library(dplyr)   # for pipe and left_join()

df <- df %>% 
  left_join(df2
          , by = c("Sex"="Code")   # define columns for the join
)
```

This creates the Label column which you need to further process.

Example output:

```
df
  Name Sex  Label   Sex2
1 Ind1   1   Male   Male
2 Ind2   2 Female Female
3 Ind3   1   Male   Male
4 Ind4   2 Female Female
5 Ind5   2 Female Female
```